# How to create NLog XmlLayout with indented xml message?

Tags: c#, nlog

In the 4.6 version of NLog were added some new features. One of them - XMLLayout. Is there any way to save xml-formatted message in the XMLLayout target with correct indenting? Additional question is how to do the same thing with hierarchical Property values output?

Below my config and messages code

```
<target name="xmlFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="my_log.xml" maxArchiveFiles="3" archiveNumbering="Sequence" archiveDateFormat="dd-mm-yyyy" archiveOldFileOnStartup="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <layout xsi:type="XmlLayout" indentXml="true" includeAllProperties="true" includeMdc="true">
    <attribute name="logger" layout="${logger}" />
    <attribute name="callsite" layout="${callsite}" />
    <attribute name="line" layout="${callsite-linenumber}" />
    <element name="message" value="${message}" />
    <element name="exception" value="${exception:format=toString}" />
  </layout>
</target>
```

1. Testing xml-text. Message for test:

```
"<hello person=\"x\"><child>child value</child></hello>"
```

Result is not indented:

```
<logevent logger="Logs" callsite="WriteLogMessages.LogMessages" line="36">
  <message><hello person="x"><child>child value</child></hello></message>
</logevent>
```

2. Testing properties. LogEventInfo for test:

```
var root = new Dictionary<string, object>();
var branches = new Dictionary<string, object>();
var leaf = new Dictionary<string, object>();
leaf["leaf"] = "This is the leaf";
branches["branches"] = leaf;
root["root"] = branches;

var logEvent = new LogEventInfo();
logEvent.Level = logLevel;
logEvent.Message = message;
logEvent.Properties["properties test"] = root;
```

Result:

```
<logevent logger="Logs" callsite="WriteLogMessages.LogMessages" line="26">
  <message>Test message.</message>
  <property key="properties test">
  <property key="root">
</property>
```

I understand that may be need to create a wrapper over Dictionary and override ToString(), but result goes to the problem number 1.

Expected result:

```
<logevent logger="Logs" callsite="WriteLogMessages.LogMessages" line="36">
  <message>
    <hello person="x">
      <child>child value</child>
    </hello>
  </message>
</logevent>
```

Comment: Thank you for reporting this bug that you thought was a feature :). NLog should perform xml-encode of the message-string. NLog will not try an parse your random message-string as xml, and then output it again as indented xml.

Comment: Created https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/3198

Comment: By default the NLog XmlLayout will only perform simple reflection of object-properties (To avoid serializing the entire world). But if you have an advanced object-graph with collections then you can configure `MaxRecursionLimit = 10` See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/XmlLayout

Comment: Ok! Thanks a lot!

Comment: NLog 4.6.1 has been released that fixes the bug/feature: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize and elaborate the comments,

There was a bug, that is fixed in NLog 4.6.1

Nested properties aren't serialized by default. You need `MaxRecursionLimit` (e.g. 10, the default is 1),

So in this case:

```xml
 <layout xsi:type="XmlLayout" indentXml="true" 
         maxRecursionLimit="10"
 ... />
```

See [XML Layout docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/XmlLayout)